# Failed to build gem native extension - extconf.rb not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby

When trying to install

```
'bcrypt-ruby', :lib => 'bcrypt'
```

and

```
'hpricot'
```

I get this in both cases (Using Windows XP)

```
C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)
```

I installed from here http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ Rb 1.8.6, including the devkit

any hints?, thanks

Answer (score 11):

There's now an entry in the [RubyInstaller Wiki](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#gems_fails_autorun) that addresses this potential issue:

> Using a command prompt, invoke the
>   following commands:
>
> ```
> REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"
> REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"
> ```
>
> Execute each line individually. Once
>   you run it, will see something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
>     CompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
>     DefaultColor    REG_DWORD    0x0
>     EnableExtensions    REG_DWORD    0x1
>     PathCompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
> ```
>
> The columns of information are Key,
>   Type and Value. If you see a key named
>   AutoRun, there is a chance this is the
>   culprit of the error you’re receiving.
>   AutoRun interferes with Ruby messing
>   with child process executing and by
>   result, affecting gem installation.
>   Please remove it with the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
> ```
>
> Once you’re done, try opening a new
>   command prompt and executing gem
>   installation again.

Comment: +1 Worked for me, did setup AutoRun myself ages ago, of course completely forgot about this by now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 You don't actually need to remove AutoRun, just make sure you are not changing working directory with your AutoRun

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, my RubyInstaller + DevKit installation worked fine on the first try. So a couple ideas:

1.) Did you start Gem from the shortcut entitled "Start Command Prompt with Ruby"? (This will ensure that the correct paths and such are included.)

2.) Are you sure that the [DevKit](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/development-kit) is installed correctly? Both of those gems do include [the extconf.rb file](http://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/ext/mri/extconf.rb), but Gem will still choke if the expected development tools are not immediately available.

(...Otherwise, the [RubyInstall mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller) might be the best place to seek help for this--or the gem's author, but it appears that he doesn't "do" Windows.)

Comment: Thanks
Not sure what you mean here : 1.) Did you start Gem from the shortcut entitled "Start Command Prompt with Ruby"? (This will ensure that the correct paths and such are included.)?

2. The setup is correct :)

Comment: The RubyInstaller folder in the Start Menu should include a shortcut labeled "Start Command Prompt with Ruby"... basically, it enables command extensions and runs `C:\Ruby\bin\setrbvars.bat` to ensure that the environment is set right.

Comment: Tried it, but no success. I'll try reinstalling ruby/devkit. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer by [Ryan Barton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018166/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-extconf-rb-not-found/5723662#5723662) didn't work, then try this. It was also pulled from the [RubyInstaller Wiki](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Using a command prompt, invoke the following command:

```
SET COMSPEC
```

The default output of that should look like:

```
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

If in the output includes something different than cmd.exe as executable, then please adjust it to use cmd.exe. Please note that the variable **must** contain a full path to the cmd.exe executable and relative paths will fail.

Some tools might change your command processor command, which interferes with Ruby invoking child processes.

The non-processed variable (that you will find inside System Properties - Environment variables) is: `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`

Change that and try to install the gem again.