# No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (Loa dError) - Installing json (1.8.0)

Tags: extconf.rb

I should probably start by saying that I am new to rails. This specific error message came up as i was trying to run bundle install. Error pops up once installation gets to json.

=============================================================================

Installing json (1.8.0)

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    D:/Dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

D:/Dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (Loa
dError)

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gem
s/json-1.8.0 for inspection.

Results logged to D:/Dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/
json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.

===============================================================================

gem_make.out log file is showing

===============================================================================

D:/Dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

D:/Dev/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

===============================================================================

I already tried running `gem install json` and essentially got the same error message. DevKit is already installed. Reinstalling it made no difference.

Ruby version is 1.9.3p392 
Rails version is 3.2.13 
OS is Windows7 64bit

installation was completed using rubyinstaller.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: resolved this issue with post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018166/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-extconf-rb-not-found

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when trying to install Cucumber using the Gemfile provided in *The Cucumber Book* (p. 299) and also with `gem install json`.

When trying `gem install cucumber` it worked:

```
Fetching: multi_json-1.8.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.8.0
...
```

hth
Frank