# Ruby Gem in Windows failed, but successfull with --verbose

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I failed to execute

```
gem install json
```

but successfully execute

```
gem install json --verbose
```

The error I received when installing without verbose is

```
ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)
extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Some configuration that might helped:

```
C:\Devkit2-32>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Devkit2-32>gem env version
2.4.1
```

Comment: Could you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018166/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-extconf-rb-not-found

Comment: OMG. I did setup AutoRun recently. And it's actually interferring with the gem? Who would tought about that. Thanks anyway. It solved my problem as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy and paste my comments here:

It looks like it's same issue of: [Failed to build gem native extension - extconf.rb not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018166/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-extconf-rb-not-found)

---

There's now an entry in the [RubyInstaller Wiki](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#gems_fails_autorun) that addresses this potential issue:

> Using a command prompt, invoke the
>   following commands:
>
> ```
> REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"
> REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"
> ```
>
> Execute each line individually. Once
>   you run it, will see something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
>     CompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
>     DefaultColor    REG_DWORD    0x0
>     EnableExtensions    REG_DWORD    0x1
>     PathCompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
> ```
>
> The columns of information are Key,
>   Type and Value. If you see a key named
>   AutoRun, there is a chance this is the
>   culprit of the error you’re receiving.
>   AutoRun interferes with Ruby messing
>   with child process executing and by
>   result, affecting gem installation.
>   Please remove it with the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
> ```
>
> Once you’re done, try opening a new
>   command prompt and executing gem
>   installation again.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @XN16. I copied the answer from original post so he could follow the solutions there. The link is stackoverflow own and I would think it won't go invalid.

Comment: @zhongxiao37 actually helped in the comment so I accepted his answer.