# Visualruby fails to install

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, installation

first thank you for your time in viewing / answering this.
Here is the steps and the error I receive when trying to install visualruby.

I have followed the instructions to the "t" from
http://www.visualruby.net/site/Download.html .

I've even bumped the version of Ruby back from latest build to 1.9.3, uninstalled and reinstall, restarted pc, uninst - reinst gtk +, etc.

---

```
Command Prompt

ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\Chris>gem install visualruby

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing visualruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for --enable-debug-build option... no

checking for -Wall option to compiler... yes

checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wextra option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... yes

checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wswitch-default option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wswitch-enum option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wundef option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wout-of-line-declaration option to compiler... no

checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... yes

checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... yes

checking for rb_define_alloc_func() in ruby.h... yes

checking for rb_block_proc() in ruby.h... yes

checking for new allocation framework... yes

checking for attribute assignment... no

checking for cairo... yes

checking for rb_cairo.h... no

*** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

        --with-opt-dir

        --without-opt-dir

        --with-opt-include

        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include

        --with-opt-lib

        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib

        --with-make-prog

        --without-make-prog

        --srcdir=.

        --curdir

        --ruby=C:/Ruby/Ruby193/bin/ruby

        --enable-debug-build

        --disable-debug-build

        --with-pkg-config

        --without-pkg-config

        --with-override-variables

        --without-override-variables



Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gtksourceview2-2.2.5 for inspection.

Results logged to C:/Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gtksourceview2-2.2.5/ext/gtksourceview2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I think you real problem is this portion of your error message: Failed to build gem native extension. C:/Ruby/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb. Maybe try and search for an answer to that problem - maybe an answer to this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018166/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-extconf-rb-not-found

Comment: Can you post your `mkmf.log` and `gem_make.out`?

Comment: @Azolo here is the [gem_make.out](http://pastebin.com/Enj1jcEi) and here is the [mkmf.log](http://pastebin.com/syZVKQFt) --both links are PasteBin.

Comment: @tmadsen Thank you for your contribution to solving this. I have tried to search for the answer as per your suggestion, unfortunately everything i find is OSX or Linux/Ubuntu related. I've tried to work thier finding in Windows, to no success.

Comment: It looks like you should probably file an issue with the gem author. =/ I can't see it looking for the header in any of the places it might be on Windows.

Comment: @Azolo thank you for helping me. It seems as though this will not work, so it is back to tcl/tk for gui's. Thanks again. Consider this closed.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't solve it. If you need any help with anything else Ruby related, I try to keep an eye on SO but you can also write to the [RubyInstaller Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/rubyinstaller)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed visualruby using Ruby 2.2.4 and its development kit from rubyinstaller.org.
Perhaps you could try 2.2.4 rather than 1.9.3

```
C:\Users\wayne>ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\wayne>gem install visualruby
Fetching: require_all-1.3.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed require_all-1.3.3
Fetching: pkg-config-1.1.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pkg-config-1.1.7
Fetching: cairo-1.15.2-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cairo-1.15.2-x86-mingw32
Fetching: glib2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed glib2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gobject-introspection-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gobject-introspection-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: pango-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pango-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: rsvg2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rsvg2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: cairo-gobject-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cairo-gobject-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gdk3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gdk3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: atk-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed atk-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gio2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gio2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gtk3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gtk3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: gtksourceview3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gtksourceview3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Fetching: visualruby-3.0.15.gem (100%)
Successfully installed visualruby-3.0.15
Parsing documentation for require_all-1.3.3
Installing ri documentation for require_all-1.3.3
Parsing documentation for pkg-config-1.1.7
Installing ri documentation for pkg-config-1.1.7
Parsing documentation for cairo-1.15.2-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for cairo-1.15.2-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for glib2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for glib2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gobject-introspection-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gobject-introspection-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for pango-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for pango-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gdk_pixbuf2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for rsvg2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for rsvg2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for cairo-gobject-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for cairo-gobject-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gdk3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gdk3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for atk-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for atk-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gio2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gio2-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gtk3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gtk3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for gtksourceview3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for gtksourceview3-3.0.8-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for visualruby-3.0.15
Installing ri documentation for visualruby-3.0.15
Done installing documentation for require_all, pkg-config, cairo, glib2, gobject-introspection, pango, gdk_pixbuf2, rsvg2, cairo-gobject, gdk3, atk, gio2, gtk3, gtksourceview3, visualruby after 9 seconds
15 gems installed
```

Comment: OOPS, I just read the following on the VisualRuby site: "There are known problems with earlier versions of Ruby and Windows. However, they've fixed the problem in Ruby version 2.3.0+" http://visualruby.net/file.Download.html